# Rollback for restful microservices and orchestrator service

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration, microservices

I am developing an orchestration service in java which makes a call to multiple microservices.

orchestration contains process method

```
 public class orchestrator {

 public void process(){
      getXXX(); ---> call to another restful microservice
      getzzz(); ---> call to another restful microservice
      AddXXX(); ---> call to another restful microservice
      updateYYY();
      updatezzzz(); 

}
}
```

If updateYYY fail I want to call something which will reverse actions for AddXXX
in our case add update are not database transactions they are calls rest services
so while reversing we need to call another operation from same restful service

Can someone propose aligent way of doing this or any design pattern

Comment: It's not exactly what you ask for, but two phase commit is a technique to achieve atomicity.

Comment: You might find something by searching for "compensation".

Comment: I read Compensation handlers but is there any implementation I can see Lot of theoretical information on this topic but not implementation example

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.

Comment: Does the call updateYYY() need any data returned by Addxxx() ? 
Can you make the call updateYYY() from the service which exposes Addxxx() ?